# How can responsive popover popup in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass

I've tried this issue coming for responsive time  can you please help me I have used it in Ionic popover content but the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFvOv.png)respondent image description here time alignment is not coming properly please tell me any idea

this problem facing I've there days please guide me